# NSMutableRLEArray objectAtIndex:effectiveRange:: Out of bounds

Tags: objective-c, ios7, nsrange, nsrangeexception

I try to assign attributes to 3 last chars of `newClock` string, which is `@"3:33:23"`.

However I  get an error when construct `NSRange`:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *mas = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:newClock];
[mas addAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor grayColor],
NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:12]}
 range:NSMakeRange(newClock.length-3,newClock.length)];
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

NSMakeRange(i, j) creates a range with location i and length j.

If for example the size of your string is 10 and your range starts in 5, and you do this:

```
NSMakeRange(5,10)
```

Your range goes from 5 to 15, so out of your string.

Try:

```
NSMakeRange(newClock.length-3,3)];
```